How to define className dynamically from a SCSS module in React component?
I've defined my button React component as follows:
import Styles from './styles.module.scss';
import { IButton } from './button.types';
const Button = (props: IButton) => {
    const { variant, title, size } = props;

    return (
        <>
            <button className={`${Styles.btn}}`} >
                {title}
            </button>
         
        </>
    );

}
export default Button

And my styles are defined as follows:
.btn {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    font-family: "rayan-sans-default";

    &.primary {
        color: $basic-25;
        background-color: $brand-500;

        &--xs {
            font-size: $font-size-xs;
            font-weight: $font-weight-medium;
            padding: 2px 10px;

        }

        &--sm {
            font-size: $font-size-sm;
            font-weight: $font-weight-medium;
            padding: 5px 14px;

        }

        &--md {}

        border-radius: $radius-xs;
    }


}

If my button component is used as follows:
<Button size="sm" variant="primary" title="primary"/>

How should my className be in the button.tsx component to be defined to have the current size class dynamically?

From what I understanding, what you want is automatically assign the values from the properties provided for Button into className?

yes, specially for the scss classes like primary--sm

I think the only way to achieve this is by constructing the key based on your SCSS structure.
let classAttributes: string[] = [Styles.btn];

if (variant) classAttributes.push(Styles[`${variant}`]);

if (variant && size) classAttributes.push(Styles[`${variant}--${size}`]);

let classes = classAttributes.join(' ');
return (
  <>
    <button className={classes}>{title}</button>
  </>
);

Demo @ StackBlitz

See if the following code helps.
Use the variant and size parameters as keys to access the properties of Styles.
const Button = (props: IButton) => {
  const { variant, title, size } = props;
  const buttonSize = `${variant}--${size}`
  const buttonClass = `${Styles.btn} ${Styles[variant]} ${Styles[buttonSize]}`;
    
  return (
    <>
       <button className={buttonClass} >
          {title}
       </button>
    </>
  );
}

